# Spring Boot ActiveMQ websocket STOMP connection with SpringMessaging 5.x.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, activemq-classic, netty

I have problem updating spring messaging form `4.x.x` to `5.x.x`. In newer version `Reactor2TcpClient` is replaced with `ReactorNettyTcpClient` which is giving me a hard time.

This is my working code using old spring messaging:

```
package com.example.websockets;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.AbstractBrokerMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.tcp.reactor.Reactor2TcpClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
class MyStompBrokerRelayMessageHandler extends DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AbstractBrokerMessageHandler stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler() {

        StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler handler = (StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler) super.stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler();

        handler.setTcpClient(new Reactor2TcpClient<>(
                new StompTcpFactory(
                "stompLink",
                stompPort,
                true)
        ));

        return handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue", "/topic")
                .setRelayHost("wssLink")
                .setRelayPort(wssPort)
                .setSystemLogin("adminLogin")
                .setSystemPasscode("adminPassword")
                .setClientLogin("clientLogin")
                .setClientPasscode("clientPassword");

        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.example.websockets;

import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.Reactor2StompCodec;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder;
import org.springframework.messaging.tcp.reactor.Reactor2TcpClient;
import reactor.Environment;
import reactor.core.config.ReactorConfiguration;
import reactor.io.net.NetStreams;
import reactor.io.net.Spec;
import reactor.io.net.config.SslOptions;
import reactor.io.net.impl.netty.NettyClientSocketOptions;

import java.util.Properties;

import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;

public class StompTcpFactory implements NetStreams.TcpClientFactory<Message<byte[]>, Message<byte[]>> {

    private final Environment environment;
    private final EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup;
    private final String host;
    private final int port;
    private final boolean ssl;

    StompTcpFactory(String host, int port, boolean ssl) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.ssl = ssl;
        this.environment = new Environment(() -> new ReactorConfiguration(emptyList(), "sync", new Properties()));
        this.eventLoopGroup = Reactor2TcpClient.initEventLoopGroup();
    }

    @Override
    public Spec.TcpClientSpec<Message<byte[]>, Message<byte[]>> apply(Spec.TcpClientSpec<Message<byte[]>, Message<byte[]>> tcpClientSpec) {
        return tcpClientSpec
                .env(environment)
                .options(new NettyClientSocketOptions().eventLoopGroup(eventLoopGroup))
                .codec(new Reactor2StompCodec(new StompEncoder(), new StompDecoder()))
                .ssl(ssl ? new SslOptions() : null)
                .connect(host, port);
    }

}
```

and here are my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-net</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.28.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my failed attempt to update dependencies I was using this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.ipc</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I replaced:

```
    @Bean
    public AbstractBrokerMessageHandler stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler() {

        StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler handler = (StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler) super.stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler();

        handler.setTcpClient(new Reactor2TcpClient<>(
                new StompTcpFactory(
                "stompLink",
                stompPort,
                true)
        ));

        return handler;
    }
```

with:

```
    @Bean
    public AbstractBrokerMessageHandler stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler() {

        StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler handler = (StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler) super.stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler();

        handler.setTcpClient(new ReactorNettyTcpClient<>(
                    "stompLing",
                    stompPort,
                    new StompReactorNettyCodec(new StompDecoder(), new StompEncoder())));

        return handler;
    }
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.